# Groovy, unexpected token in bash

Tags: bash, groovy, token

I'm trying to get a bash script working with groovy. It looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

DIR=`pwd`

MASTER="['master', 'localhost:8080']"
SLAVE="['slave', 'localhost:8081']"

gnome-terminal -e "bash -c \"cd $DIR;
                             gradle run -PappArgs=$MASTER; exec bash\""

gnome-terminal -e "bash -c \"cd $DIR;
                             gradle run -PappArgs=$SLAVE; exec bash\""
```

But I get this error:

```
startup failed:
  Script1.groovy: 1: unexpected token:  @ line 1, column 9.
     [master,
             ^
```

I read that groovy escaped characters different than bash and that could be the problem, but I haven't been able to fix it...

Comment: What is `Script1.groovy`?

Comment: might work, if the space is removed in the MASTER/SLAVE vars or even better quote it properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an extra level of quoting on the MASTER and SLAVE values.  'printf' can do it for you:

```
printf -v MASTER '%q' "['master', 'localhost:8080']"
printf -v SLAVE  '%q' "['slave', 'localhost:8081']"
```

Comment: So I replaced the MASTER and SLAVE variables with the printf, but now I get a NullPointerException instead

Edit: I get ./start.sh: 5: printf: Illegal option -v, but I can execute it in my shell directly. Not in the script though

Comment: @user1900750, it looks like you are running on a system where /bin/sh is not a link to /bin/bash.  It should work if you change the first line to `#! /bin/bash'.